# How can I startup Spacemacs with term shell opened?

Tags: spacemacs

I'd like to have a term shell opened after startup of Spacemacs. How do I have to configure `.spacemacs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Visit your `.spacemacs` file (`SPC f e d`)
2. In that file, find `defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()`
3. Inside that function, at the end, add a line like this:

`(term "/bin/bash")`

If you have nothing else in that function, it'll look something like this:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration for user code:
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs startup, after layer
configuration.
Put your configuration code here, except for variables that should be set
before packages are loaded."
  (term "/bin/bash")
)
```